# Matrix exponential for infinite infinitesimal generator

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm working with continuous-time Markov processes with countable state spaces, and I'd like to express the general form of the solution.

In the finite case I know how to do this: we write the forward equation (aka master equation) in the form
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt} = H\mathbf{p},
$$
where $H$ is an infinitesimal stochastic matrix, and then the solutions can be given in terms of the matrix exponential,
$$
\mathbf{p}(t) = e^{Ht}\mathbf{p}_0.
$$

What I want to know is whether it's correct to write the same thing in the case where the state space is countably infinite. In that case $H$ is a linear operator. (In my context, it's easiest to think of it as an infinite matrix.)

I know that I can define the exponential of an operator in the same way as the matrix exponential. However, as I understand it this isn't guaranteed to be well defined in the infinite case. It is guaranteed to work if $H$ is a bounded linear operator, but I don't have a good intuition for what that means in this context.

So the question is, what does a bounded operator amount to in the context of an infinitesimal generator of a Markov process? Is $H$ always bounded in this context? If not, are there some simple conditions on the elements of $H$ (seen as an infinite matrix) that guarantee that it's a bounded operator? If it's not a bounded operator, what does that imply about the Markov process?

Comment: Boundedness is a sufficient condition for the matrix exponential to exist, not a necessary one. Instead of checking convergence of the entire matrix exponential at once you can just check whether the series evaluated on relevant vectors converges.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thank you for that point about necessary vs sufficient, I hadn't appreciated it and have fixed the question. For the systems I'm working with I actually know the solutions, so I can just write them down - the question is really just about the correct way to present the general theory, for motivation.